# how to concatenate pre trained embedding layer and Input layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, word-embedding

```
normal_input = Input(shape=(56,))

pretrained_embeddings = Embedding(num_words, 200, input_length=max_length, trainable=False,
                                                            weights=[ft_embedding_matrix])

concatenated = concatenate([normal_input, pretrained_embeddings])

dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(concatenated)
```

My idea was to create an input with 256 dimension and pass it to a dense layer.

I got the following error.

**ValueError**: Layer concatenate_10 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: [, ]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an input to select which embedding you're using.

Since you're using 150 words, your embeddings will have shape `(batch,150,200)`, which is not possible to concatenate with `(batch, 56)` in any way. You need to transform something somehow to match the shapes. I suggest you try a `Dense` layer to transform 56 into 200...

```
word_input = Input((150,))
normal_input = Input((56,))

embedding = pretrained_embeddings(word_input)
normal = Dense(200)(normal_input)

#you could add some normalization here - read below

normal = Reshape((1,200))(normal)
concatenated = Concatenate(axis=1)([normal, embedding])
```

I also suggest, since embeddings and your inputs are from different natures, that you apply a normalization so they become more similar:

```
embedding = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(embedding)
normal = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(normal)
```

---

Another possibility (I can't say which is best) is to concatenate in the other dimension, transforming the 56 into 150 instead:

```
word_input = Input((150,))
normal_input = Input((56,))

embedding = pretrained_embeddings(word_input)
normal = Dense(150)(normal_input)

#you could add some normalization here - read below

normal = Reshape((150,1))(normal)
concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([normal, embedding])
```

I believe this is more suited to recurrent and convolutional networks, you add a new channel instead of adding a new step.

---

You could even try a double concatenation, which sounds cool :D

```
word_input = Input((150,))
normal_input = Input((56,))

embedding = pretrained_embeddings(word_input)
normal150 = Dense(150)(normal_input)
normal201 = Dense(201)(normal_input)

embedding = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(embedding)
normal150 = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(normal150)
normal201 = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)(normal201)


normal150 = Reshape((150,1))(normal150)
normal201 = Reshape((1,201))(normal201)
concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([normal150, embedding]) 
concatenated = Concatenate(axis= 1)([normal201, concatenated])
```

Comment: Thanks for  the reply, I've input of length 150 (words) and vector dimension of 200. When I call the Concatenate, it throws ```ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged```

Comment: 150 words, that's a whole new story.... you can't concatenate 150x200 with 56, it's not possible. I'll add a suggestion.

Comment: If you're using 150 words as input, yes, `(?, 150, 200)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's beacause the concatenate layer is called like that :

```
concatenated = Concatenate()([normal_input, pretrained_embeddings])
```