# Concatenation of two embeddings by keras embeddings layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using the code with some modifications to match the shapes of two different embeddings. Using reference answered[concatenate-pre-trained-embedding-layer-and-input-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60209407/how-to-concatenate-pre-trained-embedding-layer-and-input-layer).
This is connected with my previous question [embeddings of different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269926/i-want-to-concatenate-two-embeddings-using-keras-embeddings-layers-and-train-the/71286307?noredirect=1#comment126017378_71286307)
Two embeddings of shapes (14169,384) and (6063,384) from text data and knowledge graphs embeddings.

```
ip1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((14169,)) # number of input sentences 
ip2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((6063,))  

text_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(14169, 384, input_length=14169,weights=[r_text],trainable=False)(ip1) #text embeddings(14196,384)
KG_embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(6063, 384, input_length=14169,weights=[embeddings_rdf_train],trainable=False)(ip2) #knowledge graphs embeddings (6063,384)

normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Dense(14196)(ip2) #trying to match embeddings dimensions
normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((14196,1))(normal_kg)
embedding_KG = KG_embed(normal_kg)

concat = layerlist = [text_embed, embedding_KG]
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = -1)(layerlist)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation = 'relu',name='dense_1')(concat)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(outputs)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([ip1, ip2], outputs)
model.summary()
```

getting error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4409dc2687a5> in <module>()
      7 normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Dense(14196)(ip2)
      8 normal_kg = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((14196,1))(normal_kg)
----> 9 embedding_KG = KG_embed(normal_kg)
     10 
     11 concat = layerlist = [text_embed, embedding_KG]

TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable
```

could anyone please tell. How I should do according to my problem or whether I am going right?

Comment: What is your goal? Do you have a third input? If not, why are you trying to contatenate a raw input with the embeddings of the same input?

Comment: Most importantly, embeddings expect "interger indices", they do not expect the results of a dense layer.

Comment: The error you are getting is because `KG_embed` is a `tensor`, not a layer. You cannot "call a tensor". It is a tensor because you "called the layer" in the same line where you defined the layer by adding an `(ip2)` after the layer creation. But there is a whole conceptual problem to be solved there and this little programming bug will not solve the question.

Comment: okay, thanks for the response. Actually, I am trying to insert knowledge by knowledge graphs about the various entities in my textual raw dataset.(foreg: <subject, predicate, object> like Trump, USA etc). So I generated the knowledge triples (from my raw dataset) and also generated corresponding KG embeddings by RDF2vec. Now to infuse the knowledge into raw text. I need to concatenate the raw text and knowledge graphs embeddings. I am lacking now how do I concatenate these two embeddings of sizes defined above?

Comment: @Daniel Möller And after concatenation, I want to predict the classification (0 or 1) by using the same model (model. fit) and want to compare the accuracy or F1 score of the model when trained by only the raw text embeddings and when trained by (raw text+KG embeddings) and it should increase in the later case because of the infusion of the knowledge in raw text. This is my final goal.

Comment: So, you should ask a question that details everything. It's not possible to understand what you want with this. And say "contactenate these two things" doesn't help. We don't know what are these things, we don't know where they're coming from, we don't know their shapes, their types, how many inputs you have, the length of your sentences, what are they made of, etc. etc.

Comment: KG embeddings generated are of dimensions (6063,384) and they are of the same type as raw text embeddings which is numpy. ndarray. They are made of RDF triples<s,p,o>(from Dbpedia URIs). Foreg: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michigan> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#typepred> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Space>. This is called RDFtriples <sub,pred,obj> or <head,relation,tail>of graph. So I have generated the embeddings for these RDFtriples by PyRDF2Vec python library which is developed for this purpose like word2vec.

Comment: And I provided a vector size of 384. So finally embeddings size is (6063,384). As out of 14169 sentences in the raw dataset,  RDF triples are generated for only 6063 sentences. And raw text size is 14169 sentences, so embeddings dimensions for raw text (14169,384). Hope its clear?

Comment: @DanielMöller Did it help you to understand my goal what I explained above? And the input is only one dataset (.csv file with sentences and labels 0 and 1). the length of the sentences is different(10,18,...max size=400). From the same sentences, I am generated these KG embeddings by above process. Now I have two corresponding embeddings (text+KG embeddings from same dataset) which I want to concatenate and use these concatenated embeddings for a feed-forward network to perform classification(label column in dataset 0 or 1).